# How can toastr.js work in Aurelia and Typescript?

Tags: typescript, toastr, aurelia

I can't seem to get these to work together. I'm using the Aurelia CLI and have done so in a similar manner for other libraries successfully(like select2, spin, moment and numeral). I can't seem to get toastr to work though. Here is what I have so far.

First I ran `npm install toastr --save` and `typings install dt~toastr --global --save`

In `aurelia.json`, in the vendor-bundle.js section, I added a dependency as such:

```
  "jquery",
  {
    "name": "toastr",
    "path": "../node_modules/toastr/build",
    "main": "toastr.min",
    "resources": [
      "toastr.min.css"
    ],
    "deps": ["jquery"]
  }
```

---

**UPDATE: Full steps to repro**

I have these versions of these tools installed: node (6.3.0), npm (3.10.3), au (0.17.0)

Open a command prompt and type:

```
au new au-toastr
3 (Custom)
2 (Typescript)
3 (Sass)
1 (configure unit testing)
1 (Visual Studio Code)
1 (create project)
1 (install project dependencies)
cd au-toastr
npm install jquery --save
npm install toastr --save
typings install dt~jquery --global --save
typings install dt~toastr --global --save
```

Then open `aurelia.json` in an editor and add

```
"jquery",
{
"name": "toastr",
"path": "../node_modules/toastr/build",
"main": "toastr.min",
"resources": [
"toastr.min.css"
],
"deps": ["jquery"]
}
```

to the bottom of dependencies.

Comment out line 1839(`declare var $: cssSelectorHelper;`) on `typings/globals/angular-protractor/index.d.ts` due to conflict with jquery's .d.ts file.

Replace `app.ts` contents with

```
import * as toastr from 'toastr';

export class App {
  activate() {
    toastr.info('blah');
  }
}
```

OR

```
import 'toastr';

export class App {
  activate() {
    toastr.info('blah');
  }
}
```

Type `au run` in the command prompt and then open a browser and navigate to the url that the command line says the application is available at(usually `http://localhost:9000`).

---

**Attempt 1**

```
import 'toastr';

export class ViewModel {
  activate() {
    toastr.info('blah');
  }
}
```

Error: *ReferenceError: toastr is not defined*

---

**Attempt 2**

```
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import 'toastr';

@autoinject()
export class ViewModel {
  constructor(private toastr: Toastr) {
  }

  activate() {
    this.toastr.info('blah');
  }
}
```

Error: *TypeError: this.toastr.info is not a function*

---

**Attempt 3**

```
import * as toastr from 'toastr';

export class ViewModel {
  activate() {
    toastr.info('blah');
  }
}
```

Error: *TypeError: toastr.info is not a function*

---

**Attempt 4**

```
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import * as toastr from 'toastr';

@autoinject()
export class ViewModel {
  constructor(private toastr: Toastr) {
  }

  activate() {
    this.toastr.info('blah');
  }
}
```

Error: *TypeError: this.toastr.info is not a function*

---

All of the above transpile properly when I run `au build` from the command line. I get no errors.

I'm lost as to what I am missing or what else I can try. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**UPDATE:** My guess is that there is either a bug in the `aurelia-cli` or more likely I'm handling the package incorrectly somehow in regard to the `aurelia-cli` loading mechanism. When I get the typescript skeleton from their site, which is using jspm as it's module loader, and follow the same steps above, the toastr works just fine.

Any ideas how I can get this to work with the aurelia-cli?

---

Comment: What works for me (but with plain ES6+ and no TypeScript) is this: `import toastr from 'toastr';`

Comment: Yeah, that gives a transpilation error in TypeScript. As does `import {Toastr} from 'toastr';`

Comment: Have you tried Attempt 2 or 4, but with `this.toastr = toastr;` in the constructor? Unless that's something that `@autoinject()` does; I'm not really up on my Aurelia.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but with Aurelia, making the parameter private creates a property on the view model named the same as the parameter. If it didn't, then this.toastr wouldn't transpile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a lot of time and help from a friend, I was finally able to get this to work.

Only a few changes should be necessary -

`aurelia.json` needed to be updated to not use the minified version of the toastr library.

```
{
  //...
  "dependencies": [
  //...
    "jquery",
    {
      "name": "toastr",
      "path": "../node_modules/toastr",
      "main": "toastr",
      "resources": [
        "build/toastr.min.css"
      ],
      "deps": ["jquery"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The `toastr.info('here');` function invocation usually needs to happen in the attached method or after the element is available in the DOM.

To require the HTML in `app.html` needs to be updated to

```
<require from="toastr/build/toastr.min.css"></require>
```

Hope this helps.

---

**UPDATE**
Then to use it in your view model, you could do it one of a few ways:

```
import * as toastr from 'toastr';

export class App {
  attached() {
    toastr.success('here');
  }
}
```

---

```
import { success } from 'toastr';

export class App {
  attached() {
    success('here');
  }
}
```

Comment: for me, step 1 and 4 was enough.

Comment: Hello, can you complete the answer? Im still stuck on how i should now import it?