# Dynamically add to Dom with Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I've been looking at the [`aurelia-dialog`](https://github.com/aurelia/dialog/) project(focused mostly on the [renderer](https://github.com/aurelia/dialog/blob/master/src/dialog-renderer.js) piece) as I was hoping to do something similar. I like the [toastr project](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/), but can't seem to get it to work with [Aurelia CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022758/how-can-toastr-js-work-in-aurelia-and-typescript)(though I can get it to work with the Typescript skeleton project). I started to work on an independent solution(I would like it to work independent from jQuery), but can't seem to understand why this isn't working.

I created a new project using the `au new` command.
I updated the `app.ts` file to contain this:

```
import {Toastr} from './toastr';

export class App {
  constructor() {
    new Toastr().showToast();
  }
}
```

and I added one other file `toastr.ts` at the same level as the `app.ts` file. It's contents are this:

```
import {DOM} from 'aurelia-pal';

export class Toastr {
    showToast() {
        let body = DOM.querySelectorAll('body')[0];
        let toastrContainer = DOM.getElementById('toastr-container');

        if(!toastrContainer) {
            toastrContainer = DOM.createElement('div');
            toastrContainer.id = 'toastr-container';
            toastrContainer.textContent = 'boo';
            body.insertBefore(toastrContainer, body.firstChild);
        }
    }
}
```

The code runs fine and hits a breakpoint if I place it inside the `showToast` method, but when I inspect the dom in the browser, it doesn't seem to add the div to the html at all.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get this element to actually be inserted into the DOM? Is there another method I need to invoke for the html to be redrawn? I didn't see anything else like that in the `aurelia-dialog` project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the call to attached().

I am new to Aurelia too, it seems like aurelia-pal DOM doesn't work before initial rendering.

```
import {Toastr} from './toastr';

export class App {
  attached() {
    new Toastr().showToast();
  }
}
```